# bind a monadic value (m2 a) inside some other monad m1

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

Working in a Coding Dojo today I tried the following

```
example :: IO ()
example = do input <- getLine
             parsed <- parseOnly parser input
             ...
```

where `parseOnly :: Parser a -> Either String a` (from `attoparsec`) of course the compiler complained that `Either ..` is not `IO ..` essentially telling me I am mixing monads.

Of course this can be solved by

```
             case parseOnly parser input of .. -> ..
```

which is kind of unelegant, I think. Also my guess is that somebody else had this problem earlier and the solution I think is related to monad transformers, but the last bits I cannot piece together.

It also reminded me of `liftIO` - but this is the other way around I think which solves the problem of lifting an IO action happening inside some surrounding monad (more precisely `MonadIO` - say for example inside `Snap` when one wants to print something to `stdout` while getting some http).

More general this problem seems to be for a `Monad m1` and a (different) `Monad m2` how can I do something like

```
example = do a <- m1Action
             b <- m2Action
             ..
```

Comment: It's not likely to be monad transformers, I don't think. `IO` can only be at the base of a monad transformer stack.

Comment: @dfeuer Are you sure? `ExceptT IO e` is a perfectly reasonable monad (built out of transformers) to which both `Either e` and `IO` actions can reasonably be lifted.

Comment: @DanielWagner, that's a good point. `IO` is still at the base, so you have to wrap the whole thing in `runExceptT` or whatever, but on the inside things are more convenient. user3237465 has turned that into an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't, in general. The whole do block has to be one specific monad (because `example` needs to have some specific type). If you could bind an arbitrary other monad inside that do block, you'd have `unsafePerformIO`.

Monad transformers allow you to produce one monad combining the kinds of things multiple other monads can do. But you have to decide that *all* the actions in your do block use the same monad transformer stack to use those, they're not a way to arbitrarily switch monads mid do-block.

Your solution with `case` only works because you've got a particular known monad (Either) that has a way of extracting values from inside it. Not all monads provide this, so it's impossible to build a general solution without knowing the particular monads involved. That's why the do block syntax doesn't provide such a shortcut.

Answer (score 4):

In general, monad transformers are for this kind of interleaving. You can use `ExceptT`

```
example :: IO (Either String ())
example = runExceptT $ do
    input <- liftIO getLine
    parsed <- parseOnly parser input
    ...
```

Note that `parseOnly` must return `ExceptT String IO a` for some `a`. Or better `ExceptT String m a` for any `m`. Or if you want `parseOnly` to return `Either String a` it's

```
example :: IO (Either String ())
example = runExceptT $ do
    input <- lift getLine
    parsed <- ExceptT $ return $ parseOnly parser input
    ...
```

But I think all you need is just

```
eitherToIO :: Either String a -> IO a
eitherToIO (Left s)  = error s
eitherToIO (Right x) = return x

parseOnly :: ... -> String -> Either String Int

example :: IO ()
example = do
    input  <- getLine
    parsed <- eitherToIO $ parseOnly parser input
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to make that expression *type check*; just as in pure code. Here,

```
... = do a <- act1  -- m1 monad
         b <- act2  -- m2 monad
         ...
```

de-sugars to:

```
... = act1 >>= (\a -> act2 >>= \b -> ...)
```

`>>=` is of signature:

```
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

the outer *bind* is specialized with `m1`, so it expects that the expression inside parenthesis be of type: `a -> m1 b`, whereas the inner bind is specialized with `m2`, so the expression inside parenthesis will be of type `a -> m2 b`:

```
-- outer bind expects (    \a   ->   m1 b      )
             act1 >>= (\a -> act2 >>= \b -> ...)
-- inner bind results (    \a   ->   m2 b      )
```

for this to *type check*, you need a function of signature `m2 b -> m1 b` in between the two; that is what [`lift`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Class.html#v:lift) does for a **certain class** of `m2` and `m1` monads: namely `m1 ~ t m2` where `t` is an instance of `MonadTrans`:

```
lift :: (Monad m, MonadTrans t) => m a -> t m a
```