# Multiple monads in one do-block

Tags: haskell

I am currently trying to learn Haskell and I really cannot understand the concept of using just one one monad in do-block. If I have `foo :: Int -> Maybe Int` and want to use for example function `hIsEOF :: Handle -> IO Bool` in this function. Can someone please explain me on some basic example how would I use `hIsEOF` and could somehow work with `Bool`?

I have been trying to search here and on google, but I always run into some advanced stuff where basically noone explains how, they just give advice on how to fit it right into OP's code. I saw monad transformers mentioned in those threads but even after reading few resources, I cannot seem to find the right way on how to use them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short answer is no. do notation is based on two things

```
return :: a -> m a
>>= :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

Notice in `>>=` that although you can work with two different inner types (`a` and `b`), it only works with one outer type, one monad (`m`). Both `m a` and `a -> m b` are the same monad.

The longer answer is, you have to convert them to the same monad. For example, `Maybe` can be converted to `IO` like so:

```
maybeToIO Nothing = error "No thing"
maybeToIO (Just a) = return a
```

Monads, in general, can not be converted into each other though, except in special cases.

---

So why does `>>=` only work with one monad? Well just look at [this](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:-62--62--61-). It is *defined* so as to work with a single monad at a time, and do-notation is *defined* to work with `>>=`. The reasons why this definition was chosen is somewhat complicated, but I can edit it in if someone wants.

You could come up with your own `>>=` that works with multiple monads, and then use [rebindable syntax](https://ocharles.org.uk/blog/guest-posts/2014-12-06-rebindable-syntax.html), but this would probably be hard.

Comment: Thanks. So conclusion is that I need to somewhat convert between them. Is function like yours `maybeToIO` common and good practice in Haskell code? I recently have to do one project in Haskell and do not want to produce some kind of spaghetti code. Also, I recently found out that doing something like `foo :: Int -> IO (Maybe Int)` seems to kinda work for me, but is it bad thing to do? Is it ugly?

Comment: It may also help to see how do notation is desugared into the standard monadic operators. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Syntactic_sugar#Do_notation

Comment: @MarekMilkovič I would say only for IO, since IO is error-prone anyway. In general, each monad conversion has to be done differently, and is occasionally impossible. Also, you will find that `foo` won't really be that useful (in particular, most uses of `foo` will have a better way to do it.)

Comment: @MarekMilkovič Note that you can convert both of them into a *third* monad. That is what behzad.nouri is doing. He converts both `IO` and `Maybe` into `MaybeT IO`, a kind of fusion of the two monads.

Comment: @PyRulez I'll probably need more time to dive into Haskell world and play around first a bit before actually starting my school project. I'll accept your answer since you were first, but both answers here were really useful and learned me something. Thanks again.

Answer (score 12):

With monad transformers, all you need to do is

1. change the function signature from `Int -> Maybe Int` to

   ```
   foo :: Int -> MaybeT IO Int
   ```
2. [**lift**](https://wiki.haskell.org/Lifting#Monad_lifting) all the IO actions inside the `do` block (or `liftIO` in this case). See [here why you need this lifting and what exactly it does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34913872/625914).
3. run the function using `runMaybeT`

A minimal example would be:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans (lift)
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe (MaybeT, runMaybeT)

import System.IO (openFile, hClose, hSeek, hIsEOF)
import System.IO (IOMode(ReadMode), SeekMode(AbsoluteSeek))

foo :: Int -> MaybeT IO Int
foo i = do
    h <- lift $ openFile "test.txt" ReadMode
    -- move the handle i bytes ahead
    lift . hSeek h AbsoluteSeek $ fromIntegral i
    eof <- lift $ hIsEOF h  -- check if hit end of file
    lift $ hClose h
    if eof then fail "eof!" else return i
```

then,

```
\> runMaybeT $ foo 1
Just 1
\> runMaybeT $ foo 100  -- would hit eof
Nothing
```

what you get out of this would be of the type:

```
(runMaybeT . foo) :: Int -> IO (Maybe Int)
```

Comment: Thank you. I seem to start getting the concept, but I have one question. Is this a preferable way of doing what I need, or should I reconsider my design? It's just that it seems for my like I would have to have `-> IO a` in almost every single function.

Comment: @MarekMilkovič It depends on how you want errors to propagate (do you want to use exceptions, or `Nothing`s.)

Comment: @MarekMilkovič ideally only very few small functions should do IO. Everything else should be pure